How to handle dynamically created buttons and their functionality at QGIS Plug-ins
I am making my first plug-in and I created a plug in with the plug-in builder. As far as I understand, and please correct me if I am wrong, the plug_in_dialog.py script should handle all the dialog things related i.e. elements of the GUI and the plug_in.py should handle the functionality of the app.
On top of that hypothesis I have created a QtWidgets.QMainWindow which creates dynamically some buttons and I want to connect to those buttons a function for selecting files and pass that list of files to the plug_in.py script to continue with the operation.
So the code on my plug_in.py looks like this:
def initGui(self):
    """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

    icon_path = ':/plugins/QC_Tools/icon.png'
    self.add_action(
        icon_path,
        text=self.tr(u'QC_Tools'),
        callback=self.run,
        parent=self.iface.mainWindow())

    # will be set False in run()
    self.first_start = True
    
    self.dlg = QC_ToolsMainWindow() 


    for attr_name in dir(self.dlg):
        if isinstance(getattr(self.dlg, attr_name), QtWidgets.QPushButton):  # Check if the attribute is a QPushButton
            button = getattr(self.dlg, attr_name)
            button.clicked.connect(self.setTheTask)

And the buttons are created from the plug_in_dialog.py like this:
def create_check_layout(self, check_label):
    #Create the layout for the check
    self.cleanupLayout()
    group_box_title = f'{check_label}'
    group_box = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(group_box_title)
    group_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

    for label_text in ['DSM', 'DTM', 'ORTHOS']:
        sub_group_box = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(label_text)
        sub_group_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel(label_text)
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Select Files')
        setattr(self, f'{label_text}_{check_label}', button)
        print(getattr(self, f'{label_text}_{check_label}'))
        
        sub_group_layout.addWidget(label)
        sub_group_layout.addWidget(button)
        sub_group_box.setLayout(sub_group_layout)
        group_layout.addWidget(sub_group_box)

    group_box.setLayout(group_layout)
    return group_box

but this never works and when I print the attr_names the buttons are not there. My guess is that this is created once and never updated after the buttons are created. How can I cope with that?

First of all, don't implement your code in initGui if you not know what are you doing. initGui initialazies action, to run your plugin. Better add your code in run method, so when you click at icon, your plugin will starts.
Second, I'm not shure that adding second QMainWindow  is a good idea,  cos QGIS has his own QMainWindow , create your plugin as QDialog e.g.
